# angular2 - Cannot match any routes when URL contains query parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to link to a confirm email URL with a confirmation token, but angular2 refuses to resolve the url when I include the query parameters.

The URL looks like this: `http://localhost:4200/account/confirm-email;userid=33174f7d-0ca9-4770-86d1-4ec04e53062e;token=qLkA+g/5rquoPC16+fRLx7sbVvz061tKiwTKm5Yd/lghA6vRPkDLm4/93JdQkaPIlrZbrPrBNwM3h5PSpObHTA2tF6bbGCJD3IiFwQaPNc2NT5ekDIrVmfV1RzTGfzJUZcrtErTfkA2ypUc1AWc5LLdYZjF0KYwTsg0S+jQ2UJgOwU9J5uNHZURrwfvvriIW`

This is my router `app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/+dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'media',
    loadChildren: 'app/+media/media.module#MediaModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'location',
    loadChildren: 'app/+location/location.module#LocationModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: 'app/+login/login.module#LoginModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: 'app/+account/account.module#AccountModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    redirectTo: '/account/register'
  },
  {
    path: 'unauthorized',
    component: UnauthorizedComponent
  },
  // {
  //   path: '**',
  //   redirectTo: '/dashboard'
  // }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is the routing config of the account module:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AccountComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'confirm-email',
    component: ConfirmEmailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'finish-registration',
    component: FinishRegistrationComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: []
})
export class AccountRoutingModule {}
```

When I call the app with this URL the path matching works but all query params are undefined: `http://localhost:4200/account/confirm-email?userid=33174f7d-0ca9-4770-86d1-4ec04e53062e;token=qLkA+g/5rquoPC16+fRLx7sbVvz061tKiwTKm5Yd/lghA6vRPkDLm4/93JdQkaPIlrZbrPrBNwM3h5PSpObHTA2tF6bbGCJD3IiFwQaPNc2NT5ekDIrVmfV1RzTGfzJUZcrtErTfkA2ypUc1AWc5LLdYZjF0KYwTsg0S+jQ2UJgOwU9J5uNHZURrwfvvriIW`

How do I need to configure the routing for it to work?

Comment: path: 'confirm-email' should be path: 'confirm-email/:userid/:token', then your shoud be able to access the parans from the router class

Comment: `'app/**+**account/account.module#AccountModule'` is this correct?

Comment: The + is a naming convetion for async loaded child modules and makes no difference.
@Fals Setting it to `confirm-email/:userid/:token` doesn't work. Also if I set the url to use `/` instead of the `;`. The url still does not match.

Comment: @Silthus you have lot of unscaped html characteres inside your token

Comment: @Fals yes you are correct. The problem were the unescaped characters. I wrapped them inside an UrlBase64Encoding and now everything works.